# Spark multiple applications in WAITING state without any RUNNING driver

Tags: apache-spark

There were a lot of applications in WAITING state though there were no active drivers for those application.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/vis.min.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/webui.css" type="text/css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/timeline-view.css" type="text/css"/><script src="/static/sorttable.js"></script><script src="/static/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script><script src="/static/vis.min.js"></script><script src="/static/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script><script src="/static/initialize-tooltips.js"></script><script src="/static/table.js"></script><script src="/static/additional-metrics.js"></script><script src="/static/timeline-view.js"></script><script src="/static/log-view.js"></script><script src="/static/webui.js"></script><script>setUIRoot('')</script>

        <title>Spark Master at spark://test-5-sparkMaster:7077</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
              <h3 style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;">
                <a style="text-decoration: none" href="/">
                  <img src="/static/spark-logo-77x50px-hd.png"/>
                  <span class="version" style="margin-right: 15px;">2.1.0</span>
                </a>
                Spark Master at spark://test-5-sparkMaster:7077
              </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12">
            <ul class="unstyled">
              <li><strong>URL:</strong> spark://test-5-sparkMaster:7077</li>
              <li>
                    <strong>REST URL:</strong> spark://test-5-sparkMaster:6066
                    <span class="rest-uri"> (cluster mode)</span>
                  </li>
              <li><strong>Alive Workers:</strong> 1</li>
              <li><strong>Cores in use:</strong> 4 Total,
                4 Used</li>
              <li><strong>Memory in use:</strong>
                20.0 GB Total,
                18.0 GB Used</li>
              <li><strong>Applications:</strong>
                29 <a href="#running-app">Running</a>,
                21 <a href="#completed-app">Completed</a> </li>
              <li><strong>Drivers:</strong>
                2 Running,
                0 Completed </li>
              <li><strong>Status:</strong> ALIVE</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div><div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12">
            <h4> Workers </h4>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">Worker Id</th><th width="" class="">Address</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory</th></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
      <td>
          <a href="http://10.247.247.144:8081">worker-20170903103903-10.247.247.144-57170</a>
      </td>
      <td>10.247.247.144:57170</td>
      <td>ALIVE</td>
      <td>4 (4 Used)</td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="20480.18432">
        20.0 GB
        (18.0 GB Used)
      </td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
          </div>
        </div><div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12">
            <h4 id="running-app"> Running Applications </h4>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">Application ID</th><th width="" class="">Name</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory per Node</th><th width="" class="">Submitted Time</th><th width="" class="">User</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Duration</th></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903103909-0049">app-20170903103909-0049</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 10:39:09</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>22 min</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903103408-0047">app-20170903103408-0047</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 10:34:08</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>27 min</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903103408-0046">app-20170903103408-0046</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 10:34:08</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>27 min</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903102808-0045">app-20170903102808-0045</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 10:28:08</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>33 min</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903102808-0044">app-20170903102808-0044</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 10:28:08</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>33 min</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903020108-0043">app-20170903020108-0043</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 02:01:08</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.0 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903020108-0042">app-20170903020108-0042</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 02:01:08</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.0 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903015855-0041">app-20170903015855-0041</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:58:55</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.0 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903015855-0040">app-20170903015855-0040</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:58:55</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.0 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903015608-0039">app-20170903015608-0039</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:56:08</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.1 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903015608-0038">app-20170903015608-0038</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:56:08</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.1 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903015413-0037">app-20170903015413-0037</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:54:13</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.1 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903015413-0036">app-20170903015413-0036</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:54:13</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.1 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903015153-0035">app-20170903015153-0035</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:51:53</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.1 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903015153-0034">app-20170903015153-0034</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:51:53</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.1 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903015046-0033">app-20170903015046-0033</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:50:46</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.2 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903015043-0032">app-20170903015043-0032</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:50:43</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.2 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014859-0031">app-20170903014859-0031</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:48:59</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.2 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014858-0030">app-20170903014858-0030</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:48:58</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.2 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014713-0029">app-20170903014713-0029</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:47:13</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.2 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014713-0028">app-20170903014713-0028</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:47:13</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.2 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014453-0027">app-20170903014453-0027</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:44:53</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.3 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014453-0026">app-20170903014453-0026</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:44:53</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.3 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014309-0025">app-20170903014309-0025</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:43:09</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.3 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014309-0024">app-20170903014309-0024</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:43:09</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.3 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014158-0023">app-20170903014158-0023</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:41:58</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.3 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014158-0022">app-20170903014158-0022</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:41:58</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.3 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014048-0021">app-20170903014048-0021</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:40:48</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>WAITING</td>
      <td>9.3 h</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903014048-0020">app-20170903014048-0020</a>

      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="">test-L-Correlation</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="16384">
        16.0 GB
      </td>
      <td>2017/09/03 01:40:48</td>
      <td>root</td>
      <td>RUNNING</td>
      <td>9.3 h</td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
          </div>
        </div><div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
               <div class="span12">
                 <h4> Running Drivers </h4>
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">Submission ID</th><th width="" class="">Submitted Time</th><th width="" class="">Worker</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory</th><th width="" class="">Main Class</th></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
      <td>driver-20170903010850-0001 </td>
      <td>Sun Sep 03 01:08:50 IST 2017</td>
      <td><a href="http://10.247.247.144:8081">
          worker-20170903103903-10.247.247.144-57170</a>
      </td>
      <td>RUNNING</td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="1">
        1
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="1024">
        1024.0 MB
      </td>
      <td>TestRunner</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td>driver-20170903010850-0000 </td>
      <td>Sun Sep 03 01:08:50 IST 2017</td>
      <td><a href="http://10.247.247.144:8081">
          worker-20170903103903-10.247.247.144-57170</a>
      </td>
      <td>RUNNING</td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="1">
        1
      </td>
      <td sorttable_customkey="1024">
        1024.0 MB
      </td>
      <td>TestRunner</td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
               </div>
             </div>
        </div><div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span12">
            <h4 id="completed-app"> Completed Applications </h4>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">Application ID</th><th width="" class="">Name</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory per Node</th><th width="" class="">Submitted Time</th><th width="" class="">User</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Duration</th></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="app?appId=app-20170903013808-0019">app-20170903013808-0019</a>

      </td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
          </div>
        </div><div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                  <h4> Completed Drivers </h4>
                  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped sortable">
      <thead><th width="" class="">Submission ID</th><th width="" class="">Submitted Time</th><th width="" class="">Worker</th><th width="" class="">State</th><th width="" class="">Cores</th><th width="" class="">Memory</th><th width="" class="">Main Class</th></thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Not sure why the system went to this state but during this period all workers went on multiple restarts.

I tried to recreate the issue in a docker environment but each time I restart a worker , the driver is going to "RELAUNCHING" state and associated application ends with state "FINISHED"

Anyone have any idea on this ??

Thanks in advance.

//